# Syntax Error on Token ",", MemberValuePair expected after this token

Tags: eclipse, minecraft

First, let me show you the code

```
package com.memio4.mod;

import com.memio4.mod.proxy.CommonProxy;

import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod.Instance;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.SidedProxy;

@Mod(modid = Reference.MOD_ID, name = Reference.NAME, version = Reference.VERSION, acceptedMinecraftVersions = Reference.ACCEPTED_VERSIONS)
public class Tutorial {

    @Instance
    public static Tutorial instance;

    @SidedProxy(clientSide = Reference.CLIENT_PROXY_CLASS, serverSide = Reference.SERVER_PROXY_CLASS)
    public static CommonProxy proxy;


}
```

And well, I don't know what to do, I have tried to put a semi-colon, leave it without it, but it turns even worse. I have not solve this issue yet, so please help me.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Which token is it complaining about?

Comment: About a comma in the line 5, rigth after Reference.VERSION

Comment: Something strange happened; i continued coding until that line its now located in line 13, but the text now located in line 5 it's also with the same error, why? 
Now is this: 
net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod.EventHandler; 

the error is in the Mod.